# Coordinating Publicity

Tags: discussion, publicity

I'd like to use this question to help coordinate the publicity of GFH during beta.

We need everyone to help where you can. The goal is to get the word out to as many different people as possible about this site. I'm not going to give you specific wording, because it's best if everybody provides their own short personal message of what they want to say.

A few examples to follow:

1. [Press release - use your own version of this](http://www.geneapress.com/2012/10/genealogy-family-history-question.html) as an announcement to send to societies or groups.
2. [Blog post - use your own version of this](http://www.beholdgenealogy.com/blog/?p=1135) for newsgroups or your own blog.
3. For your social networks (Facebook, Twitter, Google+, etc). Members of my G+ circles can [see my actual example here](https://plus.google.com/106257958448273208907/posts/JhG7KqHhZby)), otherwise [see a copy in my answer below](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1212/29).

Never use the same wording. That way they index uniquely on Google and people will run into them with different searches. Make it personal, you to them.

**Everybody:** please post to your own blog if you have a blog genealogists follow, and into your social account streams if you network with other genealogists. The key metric is that if you don't think at least 20 genealogists will see your post, then don't bother.

**Places to Contact:** We want to you to contact any societies, newsgroups and genealogy bloggers that you know and work with and that know you. Ask them to pass the information about GFH to their members or readers. Make the message personal to them, and they'll very likely be happy to pass it on.

We shouldn't spam societies, groups, newsgroups, or the internet in general, so we should coordinate the sending so only one person contacts each one. We should contact them once now. If you think another nudge is worthwhile, then contact them once more in about 2 months just before the end of the beta.

In order to coordinate this, please edit this post and add the places that have been contacted to the list below. If they post something, a link to it would be nice.

Thanks. Together, we're creating a great thing for genealogists.

---

**Genealogy blogs contacted**

- [GeneaPress](http://www.geneapress.com/2012/10/genealogy-family-history-question.html), Oct 22, lkessler

- [Genea-Musings by Randy Seaver](http://www.geneamusings.com/2012/10/genealogy-stack-exchange-is-up-and.html), Oct 22, lkessler 

- [Eastman's Online Genealogy Newsletter by Dick Eastman](http://blog.eogn.com/eastmans_online_genealogy/2012/10/genealogy-family-history-question-answer-site-now-in-public-beta.html), Oct 22, lkessler

- [PollyBlog by Polly Kimmitt](http://pk-pollyblog.blogspot.ca/), Oct 24, duncan, *Polly has not posted anything yet*

- [Geneabloggers by Thomas MacEntee](http://www.geneabloggers.com/genealogy-blogs-november-3-2012/), Nov 3, lkessler

-  [GenealogyToday by Illya D'addezio](http://www.genealogytoday.com/), Nov 10, lkessler, *Illya has not posted anything yet*

-  [The Huffington Post - Megan Smolenyak](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/megan-smolenyak-smolenyak/), Nov 10, lkessler, *Megan has not posted anything yet*

-  [Family Stories by Carolyn Pointer](http://yourfamilystory-cmpointer.blogspot.ca/), Nov 10, lkessler, *Carolyn has not posted anything yet*

-  [Dear Myrtle](http://blog.dearmyrtle.com/), Nov 10, lkessler, *Myrt has not posted anything yet*

**Newsgroups contacted**

- [Linkedin - Genealogical & Historical Research](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Genealogical-Historical-Research-106885/about) (5,726 members), Oct 27, Jeni

- [Linkedin - Family History Detective](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Family-History-Detective-2987377/about) (293 members), Oct 27, Jeni

- [Linkedin - Genealogy...Beyond the brick walls!](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?home=&gid=4102086&trk=anet_ug_hm) (609 members), Oct 27, Jeni

**Societies contacted**

- [Francis Cooke Society](http://www.franciscookesociety.org/), Oct 24, duncan, *nothing posted at website*

**Genealogy Conferences**

- [3rd Unlock The Past Genealogy Cruise](http://www.unlockthepast.com.au/events/3rd-unlock-past-history-genealogy-cruise), Feb 10-19, 2013, louis to publicize

- [Who Do You Think You Are, London England](http://www.whodoyouthinkyouarelive.com/), Feb 22-24, 2013, need a volunteer to lead publicity

- [RootsTech 2013](http://rootstech.org/), Mar 21-23, 2013, need a volunteer to lead publicity

See also: [Q&A “pushes” around Who Do You Think You Are Live and RootsTech](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/qa-pushes-around-who-do-you-think-you-are-live-and-rootstech)

Comment: Post ideas of who we should contact (if you don't want to contact them yourself) as answers.

Comment: @Duncan Rules are different for meta. 1) there is no rep to be earned, it's inherited from the main site. 2) List questions are allowed and often encouraged to promote voting. That being said, I don't think we need separate answers for this "question".

Comment: @Duncan You must have a Google+ account to view it.

Comment: per comments above, I deleted my answer. But I can't edit the question to add another one to the list. @lkessler, could you add that I contacted the Francis Cooke Society membership.

Comment: @Duncan I hadn't thought of that concern. This is where it's nice to have moderators. I've seen it where users post answers then moderators take the information and put it into the question and delete the answer. But we can't do that until we have moderators.

Comment: @Duncan - added. When I get home tonight, I'll copy the Google+ post here for you.

Comment: Made Community Wiki to open this up to more editors — http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

Comment: @Robert - Thanks for making it Community Wiki. It is no longer possible for us to do that ourselves.

Comment: @lkessler As Wiki became [widely overused and abused](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/), it became a moderator-only decision.

Comment: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2073/what-are-ways-to-collaborate-with-other-genealogist mentions two websites that seem like good communities to 'get the word to'. If there are any established participants from genealogy.se, they might know how to go about doing that.

Comment: Don't forget to 'think outside the box' - sites like Find A Grave are not 'genealogy' sites, but have many with genealogy questions.  Forums on sites like these are a way to publicize this site.

Comment: I'm going to Roots Tech 2013. There are supposed to be 4,000+ registrants... What/How exactly do you want someone to 'lead publicity' at a conference? Am I supposed to post notes to bulletin boards or something?

Comment: @Canadian- Probably worth while to make that a new meta question - re RootTech and coordinate it there.

Comment: @Luke - I rolled back your edit. The link you gave: http://blog.dearmyrtle.com/2012/08/an-independent-genealogy-site.html was Myrt posting about our site when it was still at Area 51 and we were attempting to get to beta. I had contacted Myrt after that in November once our site was in beta. She did not post anything from that correspondence.

Comment: @lkessler Thanks. Good catch. I've been thinking about asking some of these bloggers to write another something up about the site. A little more publicity wouldn't hurt and sometimes people just have to hear about something multiple times before they actually do anything.

Answer (score 2):

I posted on Linked In groups: "Genealogical & Historical Research", "Family History Detective", and "Genealogy..Beyond the brick walls!" and have had positive responses.  If you belong to other groups in Linked In you might consider posting to them.  Or, you could add comments about this site to what I posted as a couple people have done.

Comment: Jeni: Great idea to send to LinkedIn networking groups! I'm not a member of Linkedin. But I see there are quite a few people in each of those groups.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone with a talent for publicity feel like contacting http://familyhistorydaily.com/?

Answer (score 0):

Is this Q only for things like blogs or is it also for things we can do with the existing site to increase it's public awareness?

If the latter, then I think one thing that can be done is more questions, particularly ones with surnames, places, sources. This will increase our hits by people looking for the answers to their questions and then make them more likely to ask questions of their own. Using [how-should-i-distinguish-siblings-named-identically](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/222/how-should-i-distinguish-siblings-named-identically) as an example, they might hit on the name MEDWELL. That particular question is not likely to have the answer to their question, but they find this site and then ask their question here.

A related avenue of more questions is meta question [now-or-at-a-future-point-will-we-allow-a-form-of-peer-review-in-the-spirit-of](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/now-or-at-a-future-point-will-we-allow-a-form-of-peer-review-in-the-spirit-of/1349#1349). It appears people are for doing this, but not on genealogy.se and not at this point. I think it is appropriate (if you agree or disagree - let your opinions be known on that question) and I think doing it would be a kind of publicity in it's right. Those types of review questions would have more surnames, places, sources and therefore increase the traffic to the site - which is the ultimate goal of this site.

Another related answer (ie [more questions would help increase hits](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1331/157) and be a form of publicity) but it has a negative score at the moment as not the thing to focus on.

If the answer is inappropriate for this question (ie this Q is just about blogs/socieites/etc and not about self-publicity thru google hits) then I can delete this answer.

Comment: If Polly posts something, please let us know.

Comment: IMO, this is Q is about actively publicity, not SEO. Also not sure how you've got the impression that people are against the peer review thing... given that the question and both (supporting) answers have only received upvotes.

Comment: My reading of the answer that got the most upvotes was that it thought peer review was a good thing but against doing it on genealogy.se because not suitable for Q&A. It doesn't actually answer the yes/no question with a yes or no but that was how I read it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I'll go edit it to make it beyond doubt.

Comment: With your edit, I retract my comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a Google Plus account, you can't view my social network example, so I'm reproducing it here:

---

Genealogy & Family History Q&A Site is Now Public

After 20 days in Definition phase, and 31 days in Commitment Phase, and 7 days in Private Beta, the Genealogy & Family History Q&A is now open to the public. Everyone is invited to:

https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/

This is the place you go to get answers to your Genealogy problems you have from experts and genealogy enthusiasts from around the world. Ask detailed questions about how to do something, how to solve a problem you’re having, or what puzzles you in your research. You’ll get answers that will help you.

If you are an expert, then we want you here as well. You’ll find challenging questions to answer and people to help. You’ll learn things outside your expertise.

Questions such as:

- [Should I use the modern (what it is called now) or historical (what it was called) place name?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/31/29)
- [Dealing with family secrets?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/16/29)
- [One tree, or a bunch?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/329/29)
- [How should I deal with conflicting information?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/4/29)

and my own personal favourite:

- [What is the Russian town in this census listing?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1436/29)

The site is now in Public Beta and will continue to grow as more people join up to ask and answer questions.

The site is free to register and join and is unaffiliated with any genealogy company or service. Once Beta is completed, the site will be handed over to its participants who will elect moderators to ensure that it grows and remains relevant and useful.

Genealogy has always needed a good Q&A site. Finally, here it is!

Try it out. Tell everyone you know.

https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/

Note: There is also a Twitter feed from the site:
https://twitter.com/StackGenealogy

Comment: I have a google+ account, I am logged in, and I still can not follow the link to this post. Can others get there?

Comment: @Duncan - I've added you to my Google+ circles. Can you see it now?

Comment: Yes now I see it. So to follow that link, someone must be a member of your circles for the link to work. You might want to edit your question to let readers know this (eg members of my g+ circles can see an example here) and see a copy in my answer below (since it is now included in one of the answers)

Comment: @Duncan - Good idea. Done.