# How many genealogists are there and where are they worldwide by country?

Tags: discussion

Comparing our stats to worldwide stats might help us target our '[publicity](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1210/coordinating-publicity)'.

As an aside, [this link](http://www.quantcast.com/genealogy.stackexchange.com) has our current statistics. Although we are still in infancy (250 visits/day and we need 2,000 to launch), so take this with a grain of salt, it shows about 70% of visits are from the US (assuming I'm reading it correctly). Stackexchange overall is about 1/3 US and this is probably more representative of where we will end up.

I could not find data explicitly on genealogy worldwide and I confess I'm US-centric so my experience has mostly been with US-centric genealogists. I did find [myheritage's membership map](http://www.myheritage.com/myheritage-member-map). It is a non-us-based company with 64 million members. I couldn't find the by-country split but the US is large enough they treat each state like a country. Judging the height of the bars, I'd guess myheritage's 64M members have similar stats to the se stats ie that US is largest but not a majority.

I couldn't find the by-country stats for the [Association of Professional Geneaologists](http://www.apgen.org/) but that would be useful to have since we are targeting experts during the beta.

How many genealogists are there and where are they worldwide by country?

Comment: See also: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/how-many-genealogists-and-users-of-genealogy-programs/1959#1959

Answer (score 3):

Some genealogical societies give their memberships on their websites:

e.g. If I look up ["800 members" genealogy society](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22800%20members%22%20genealogy%20society) on Google, it gives:

- Toronto Branch of Ontario Genealogical Society
- (Scottish) Borders Family History Society
- Texas Jewish Historical Society
- Ottawa Branch - Ontario Genealogical Society
- Dallas Genealogical Society
- and a host of others

Assuming there are about 800 people in a population of 2 million that are involved enough in genealogy in Canada or the United States to join a society, then with 300 million people in those two countries, they might have 120,000 serious genealogists.

You could do a similar analysis for the rest of the world, and I suspect there would be way more since there's 20 times the population and probably more interest per capita in Europe.